# Program for computing Tree decomposition of a graph

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, software, treewidth

Does anybody know of an open-source program for computing Tree decomposition of graphs for a fixed "k"(width)? I know that the problem of finding Tree-Decomposition is NP-Hard for variable "k", but my input instances will be really small (~10 nodes) and "k" is fixed.

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/questions-about-finding-code-for-algorithms. Please visit the meta site before posting any answers - I'm questioning whether this question is in scope or not.

Answer (score 22):

Some of these software might help you. (Not all of them are open-source though.)

*TreeD http://www.itu.dk/people/sathi/treed/

*dlib http://dlib.net/

*QuickBB http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/vgogate/quickbb.html

*Hypertree http://www.dbai.tuwien.ac.at/proj/hypertree/downloads.html

*LibTW http://www.treewidth.com/treewidth/

Comment: I don't see the relevance of dlib; the Bayesian network join tree algorithm is related to treewidth but this implementation doesn't seem to help with computing a tree decomposition.  Radu Marinescu's treeDecomp might also be useful: http://graphmod.ics.uci.edu/group/treeDecomp

Comment: The [create join tree](http://dlib.net/algorithms.html#create_join_tree) function in dlib takes a graph and returns its tree decomposition.

Comment: @Davis: Thanks for the explicit pointer, missed that in the documentation.

Comment: The link to LibTW redirects to the author's (Dutch) consulting firm. Is there a new URL?

Answer (score 7):

If $n \sim 10$ and $k$ is fixed, then you can even afford to go with an XP algorithm like the one we implemented for our Android app.  The source code is here: [TreewidthInspector](https://github.com/drange/Grapher/blob/master/src/no/uib/ii/algo/st8/algorithms/TreewidthInspector.java), and for instance with $n \leq 13$ and $k \leq 4$ it terminates in less than a second.

It's approximately 170 lines of code and it's GPL (or MIT or BSD or whatever you should need).

Answer (score 5):

For $n\le150$ you can use the webservice over at http://treedecompositions.com/ to directly obtain and visualize a quick and reasonable decomposition, without having to compile or install anything.

Answer (score 5):

LibTW can still be found. It's at http://www.treewidth.com/treewidth/ .

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in the more modern algorithms FlowCutter ([GitHub](https://github.com/kit-algo/flow-cutter-pace17)) and the algorithms by Tamaki et al. ([GitHub](https://github.com/TCS-Meiji/PACE2017-TrackA))